# Trouble running php artisan schedule:run command

Tags: php, laravel, cron, scheduled-tasks, cpanel

[image]

When I run these command in gitbash, the command gives error. Any help will be appreciated

Error In Log File

```html
[2019-03-11 12:59:07] local.ERROR: Aborted {"exception":"[object] (Symfony\\Component\\Console\\Exception\\RuntimeException(code: 0): Aborted at C:\\xampp\\htdocs\\testapp\\vendor\\symfony\\console\\Helper\\QuestionHelper.php:129)
[stacktrace]
#0 C:\\xampp\\htdocs\\testapp\\vendor\\symfony\\console\\Helper\\QuestionHelper.php(74): Symfony\\Component\\Console\\Helper\\QuestionHelper->doAsk(Object(Symfony\\Component\\Console\\Style\\SymfonyStyle), Object(Symfony\\Component\\Console\\Question\\ConfirmationQuestion))
#1 C:\\xampp\\htdocs\\testapp\\vendor\\symfony\\console\\Style\\SymfonyStyle.php(294): Symfony\\Component\\Console\\Helper\\QuestionHelper->ask(Object(Symfony\\Component\\Console\\Input\\ArgvInput), Object(Symfony\\Component\\Console\\Style\\SymfonyStyle), Object(Symfony\\Component\\Console\\Question\\ConfirmationQuestion))
#2 C:\\xampp\\htdocs\\testapp\\vendor\\symfony\\console\\Style\\SymfonyStyle.php(222): Symfony\\Component\\Console\\Style\\SymfonyStyle->askQuestion(Object(Symfony\\Component\\Console\\Question\\ConfirmationQuestion))
#3 C:\\xampp\\htdocs\\testapp\\vendor\\symfony\\console\\Application.php(247): Symfony\\Component\\Console\\Style\\SymfonyStyle->confirm('Do you want to ...', false)
#4 C:\\xampp\\htdocs\\testapp\\vendor\\symfony\\console\\Application.php(145): Symfony\\Component\\Console\\Application->doRun(Object(Symfony\\Component\\Console\\Input\\ArgvInput), Object(Symfony\\Component\\Console\\Output\\ConsoleOutput))
#5 C:\\xampp\\htdocs\\testapp\\vendor\\laravel\\framework\\src\\Illuminate\\Console\\Application.php(89): Symfony\\Component\\Console\\Application->run(Object(Symfony\\Component\\Console\\Input\\ArgvInput), Object(Symfony\\Component\\Console\\Output\\ConsoleOutput))
#6 C:\\xampp\\htdocs\\testapp\\vendor\\laravel\\framework\\src\\Illuminate\\Foundation\\Console\\Kernel.php(122): Illuminate\\Console\\Application->run(Object(Symfony\\Component\\Console\\Input\\ArgvInput), Object(Symfony\\Component\\Console\\Output\\ConsoleOutput))
#7 C:\\xampp\\htdocs\\testapp\\artisan(37): Illuminate\\Foundation\\Console\\Kernel->handle(Object(Symfony\\Component\\Console\\Input\\ArgvInput), Object(Symfony\\Component\\Console\\Output\\ConsoleOutput))
#8 {main}
"} 
[2019-03-11 12:59:10] local.ERROR: Aborted {"exception":"[object] (Symfony\\Component\\Console\\Exception\\RuntimeException(code: 0): Aborted at C:\\xampp\\htdocs\\testapp\\vendor\\symfony\\console\\Helper\\QuestionHelper.php:129)
[stacktrace]
#0 C:\\xampp\\htdocs\\testapp\\vendor\\symfony\\console\\Helper\\QuestionHelper.php(74): Symfony\\Component\\Console\\Helper\\QuestionHelper->doAsk(Object(Symfony\\Component\\Console\\Style\\SymfonyStyle), Object(Symfony\\Component\\Console\\Question\\ConfirmationQuestion))
#1 C:\\xampp\\htdocs\\testapp\\vendor\\symfony\\console\\Style\\SymfonyStyle.php(294): Symfony\\Component\\Console\\Helper\\QuestionHelper->ask(Object(Symfony\\Component\\Console\\Input\\ArgvInput), Object(Symfony\\Component\\Console\\Style\\SymfonyStyle), Object(Symfony\\Component\\Console\\Question\\ConfirmationQuestion))
#2 C:\\xampp\\htdocs\\testapp\\vendor\\symfony\\console\\Style\\SymfonyStyle.php(222): Symfony\\Component\\Console\\Style\\SymfonyStyle->askQuestion(Object(Symfony\\Component\\Console\\Question\\ConfirmationQuestion))
#3 C:\\xampp\\htdocs\\testapp\\vendor\\symfony\\console\\Application.php(247): Symfony\\Component\\Console\\Style\\SymfonyStyle->confirm('Do you want to ...', false)
#4 C:\\xampp\\htdocs\\testapp\\vendor\\symfony\\console\\Application.php(145): Symfony\\Component\\Console\\Application->doRun(Object(Symfony\\Component\\Console\\Input\\ArgvInput), Object(Symfony\\Component\\Console\\Output\\ConsoleOutput))
#5 C:\\xampp\\htdocs\\testapp\\vendor\\laravel\\framework\\src\\Illuminate\\Console\\Application.php(89): Symfony\\Component\\Console\\Application->run(Object(Symfony\\Component\\Console\\Input\\ArgvInput), Object(Symfony\\Component\\Console\\Output\\ConsoleOutput))
#6 C:\\xampp\\htdocs\\testapp\\vendor\\laravel\\framework\\src\\Illuminate\\Foundation\\Console\\Kernel.php(122): Illuminate\\Console\\Application->run(Object(Symfony\\Component\\Console\\Input\\ArgvInput), Object(Symfony\\Component\\Console\\Output\\ConsoleOutput))
#7 C:\\xampp\\htdocs\\testapp\\artisan(37): Illuminate\\Foundation\\Console\\Kernel->handle(Object(Symfony\\Component\\Console\\Input\\ArgvInput), Object(Symfony\\Component\\Console\\Output\\ConsoleOutput))
#8 {main}
"}
```